# How to pass status codes to client side? (Redux asyncThunk)

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I want to access the `status` sent from my Express server in my React component. I am using redux to dispatch a login fetch request and want to conditionally render different childrens based on the status code received (eg. 'Incorrect Password' if status code 401)

loginmodal.js

```
    const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let result = await dispatch(login({ email, password }))
        console.log(result) //payload is undefined if incorrect password.
    }
```

userAuthSlice.js (Redux)

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    'userAuth/login',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const { email, password } = payload
        const result = await fetch(
            loginPath, {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }
        )
        console.log(result) // Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:5000/login', redirected: false, status: 401, ok: 
        const response = await result.json()
        console.log(response)
        return response
    }
)
const userAuthSlice = createSlice({
    extraReducers: {
        [login.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.isAuth = true
        },
        [login.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        },
}
```

server.js

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const plainTextPassword = req.body.password;
  User.find({ email: email }).limit(1).exec(function (err, existingUser) {
    if (existingUser.length === 0) {
      res.sendStatus(401)
    } else {
      bcrypt.compare(plainTextPassword, existingUser[0].password, function (err, response) {
        if (response === true) {
          req.session.user = existingUser[0]._id
          res.json(req.session)
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(401)
        }
      })
    }
  }
  )
})
```

In my `loginModal`, i console.log the `payload` from dispatch. My payload is undefined if my promise is rejected from incorrect password.  My payload includes the status code if its fulfilled eg correct password.  How can i get the status code / payload, even if the promise is rejected? Or is there another approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) and / or [Response.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) properties to determine if your request was successful.

If they are not, I would recommend returning a [rejected value](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors). The rejected object can have the properties you need like `status`

```js
const res = await fetch(...);
if (!res.ok) {
  // thunkApi.rejectWithValue
  return rejectWithValue({
    status: res.status,
    message: await res.text(),
  });
}
return res.json();
```

Then you can check for rejected promises and refer to the `status` in your consuming code

```js
const handleLogin = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    // needs the `.unwrap()` function call
    const result = await dispatch(login({ email, password })).unwrap();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);

    switch (err.status) {
      case 401:
        // do something for 401
        break;
      default:
        // default error handling
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you mentioned `throw res` do i have to catch it in the same script? my catch block never executes in my `handleLogin` which is a separate component/script.  ty for the help

Comment: No, you wouldn't catch it in the same script. If it's not throwing out to your `handleLogin` function, there might be some Thunk-specific thing I'm not aware of. I'll check the documentation

Comment: @benwl I've updated my answer based on the Thunk documentation